# Betfair data request commision

Tags: php, request, betfair

I've downloaded a php sample code for making data requests to betfair api. And I've read, that they are charging me, if I exceed 20 requests per second. I want to know if I exceed this limit running the following code: https://github.com/betfair/API-NG-sample-code/blob/master/php/rescript.php
How are the requests calculated anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It is free at the moment for personal use
Benefits & Features
The main benefits and features of the new API include:

Free access -  Access to API-NG is free of charge* to all developers for personal use only.
No data request charges for requests made via API-NG.
Lightweight protocol (JSON/JSON-RPC).
Configure the depth of the best prices returned to you.
Rollup available prices - you can configure the rollup amount and type.
Retrieve data from multiple markets in one request.
Retrieve matched and unmatched bets and prices available via a single request.
Search by MarketType (MATCH_ODDS, WIN, PLACE etc.) flags which remain the same, regardless of language.
Search for in-play markets.
View ‘result’ by selection after settlement.
View virtual prices.